# Using rollup in combination with babel and commonjs plugins doesn't resolve all modules

Tags: babeljs, commonjs, rollup, rollupjs

I'm using rollup with the Babel and CommonJS plugins, like this:

```js
    const inputOptions = {
        input: "...",
        plugins: [
            resolve(),
            babel({
                exclude: "node_modules/**",
                externalHelpers: true,
                include: "**/components/**/*.js",
            }),
            commonjs(),
        ],
    };
```

But what happens is that modules referenced from components don't seem to be recognized by the CommonJS plugin, they end up as plain `require(...)` statements in the output (just like the source input) where of course they cannot be resolved. Modules imported (also through `require()` statements) by modules outside the components directory get picked up properly and included in the bundle.

I have tried moving the babel plugin up (before the resolve plugin), but this had no effect. I also tried moving it down, but then Rollup chokes on the JSX in the components.

I also tried removing the `include` option, so that all files go through Babel and then the result is that no modules get picked up besides the entry point, so it really seems like the Babel and CommonJS plugins aren't playing along nicely, though I can hardly imagine I'm the only one with a setup like this. Am I missing something?

**Update**: One other thing that I notice is that the files for which the requires() aren't recognized, aren't properly exported either. Instead, for each component that fails, I see this in the output bundle:

```
module.exports = ComponentName;

var componentName = /*#__PURE__*/Object.freeze({

});
```

The `module.exports` line comes from the source, but that `Object.freeze()` statement is something rollup adds, maybe because it doesn't see any default export?

To add a bit of extra confusion: There's actually one component that gets transpiled by Babel and for which the module resolution works and the requires() get replaced like you'd expect, but all the components included from that component in turn have the defective behavior described above.

**Update 2**: I have been able to reproduce the problem in a minimal example as well, and it allowed me to pinpoint why things worked for the one component, but not by the components it includes in turn. Apparently, functional React components work properly, but class components trigger the issue. So now my hypothesis is that the Babel transform for ES6 classes somehow confuses the CommonJS plugin.

**Update 3**: As I believe this is a bug, I have also created issues with the relevant projects: https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel/issues/297 and https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/369