# how to use commonjs rollup and babel together

Tags: babeljs, commonjs, rollup

I have found several question about this problem.
The best relate to my problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256079/using-rollup-in-combination-with-babel-and-commonjs-plugins-doesnt-resolve-all)

I cannot understand how to right configure my app.

I must use commonjs and target to Node 10 syntax.

I have an example file:
example.js

```js
const Html = require('./Html');
```

Html.js

```js
/**
 * Modulo Html
 * @module Html
 */
// Routes will be rendered into children
/*
 * This module give an function with fixed title and id
 * for root element
 * 
 * @param {Object} param0 
 * @param {string} param0.title 
 * @param {string} [param0.idRoot='root'] 
 * @returns {function({childern: JSX.Element}):JSX.Element}
 */
module.exports = function Html({ title, idRoot='root' }) {
    return (
      /*
       * 
       * @param {Object} param0 
       * @param {JSX.Element} param0.children 
       * @returns {JSX.Element}
       */
      function ({children}) {
        return (
          <html>
            <head>
              <title>{title}</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <div id="{idRoot}">{children}</div>
            </body>
          </html>
        );
      }
    );
};
```

my .babelrc is:

```json
{
    "plugins": [
        [
            "babel-plugin-inferno"
            , {
                "imports": true 
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

my rollup.config.js is:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

let commonPlugins = [
      , babel({
        plugins: [
          '@babel/plugin-external-helpers'
        ]
        , extensions: [
          ".jsx"
          , ".js"
        ]
        , exclude: "node_module/**"
        , babelHelpers: "external"
        , presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-react'
          ]
          , [
            '@babel/preset-env'
            , {
                loose: true 
              , modules: false
              , targets: {
                browsers: '> 1%, IE 11, not op_mini all, not dead'
                , node: 10
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      })
      , resolve({ 
        main: true
        , extensions: [
          '.jsx'
          , '.js'
          , '.mjs'
          , '.json'
          , '.node'
        ]
        , preferBuiltins: false
      })
      , commonjs({
        include: [
          'src/**/*.js'
          , 'src/**/*.jsx'
        ]
        , ignoreGlobal: true
        , transformMixedEsModules: true
      })
];
let commonExtenal = [
      'inferno'
      , 'inferno-server'
      , 'inferno-router'
      , 'fastify'
      , 'fastify-plugin'
      , 'assert'
]
export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.jsx'
    , output: {
        file: 'dist/bundle.js',
        format: 'cjs'
      }
    , plugins: commonPlugins
    , external: commonExtenal
  }
  , {
      input: 'src/example.js'
      , output: {
          file: 'dist/example.js'
          , format: 'cjs'
          , exports: 'default'
        }
      , plugins: commonPlugins
      , external: commonExtenal
  }
]
```

I have try all order combination for 2 week but allways I get this example.js in **dist** folder:

```js
'use strict';

var require$$0 = ...
var inferno = require('inferno');

function _interopDefaultLegacy (e) { return e && typeof e === 'object' && 'default' in e ? e : { 'default': e }; }

var require$$0__default = /*#__PURE__*/_interopDefaultLegacy(require$$0);

/**
 * Modulo Html
 * @module Html
 */
// Routes will be rendered into children

/*
 * This module give an function with fixed title and id
 * for root element
 * 
 * @param {Object} param0 
 * @param {string} param0.title 
 * @param {string} [param0.idRoot='root'] 
 * @returns {function({childern: JSX.Element}):JSX.Element}
 */
module.exports = function Html(_ref) {
  var title = _ref.title,
      _ref$idRoot = _ref.idRoot;
  return (
    /*
     * 
     * @param {Object} param0 
     * @param {JSX.Element} param0.children 
     * @returns {JSX.Element}
     */
    function (_ref2) {
      var children = _ref2.children;
      return inferno.createVNode(1, "html", null, [inferno.createVNode(1, "head", null, inferno.createVNode(1, "title", null, title, 0), 2), inferno.createVNode(1, "body", null, inferno.createVNode(1, "div", null, children, 0, {
        "id": "{idRoot}"
      }), 2)], 4);
    }
  );
};

var Html = /*#__PURE__*/Object.freeze({
    __proto__: null
});
```

What is wrong: in example.js no export have to do and `var Html = /*#__PURE__*/Object.freeze({ ...` haven't to exist, the first function Html is right.

What is the right configuration to get plugin work well?

my package.json is:

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "prebublish": "npm run build",
    "build": "rollup --config",
    "start": "node ./dist/example.js"
  },
  "standard": {
    "ignore": [
      "*.jsx"
    ]
  },
  "targets": {
    "node": "current"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "inferno": "^7.4.6",
    "inferno-server": "^7.4.6",
    "inferno-router": "^7.4.6"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.2.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-buble": "^0.21.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^16.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-inferno": "^6.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "inferno": "^7.4.6",
    "inferno-router": "^7.4.6",
    "inferno-server": "^7.4.6",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.6",
    "rollup": "^2.33.1",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "standard": "^16.0.0",
    "tap": "^14.10.8"
  }
}
```

help!

best regards,
Leonardo

Answer (score 1):

The solution was avoid to use `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`:
I do not know if this plugin is buggy or if I am not be able to use it in the right manner.

Not using the plugin bring me to move all import export in ES6 module syntax to be understend by rollup.

by now using `gulp`, `rollup`, `@rollup/plugin-babel` only on jsx file, `babel-plugin-inferno`, `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` I can compile an example using `fastify`, `inferno`, `hyperscript` or `JSX` syntax together.

this is my gulpfile.js (this have to be in commonjs):

```js
const { series } = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
const rollup = require('rollup');
const fs = require('fs')
const { nodeResolve } = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve');
const { babel } = require('@rollup/plugin-babel');

let commonPlugins = [
      , nodeResolve({ 
        main: true
        , extensions: [
          '.jsx'
          , '.js'
          , '.mjs'
          , '.json'
          , '.node'
        ]
        , preferBuiltins: false
      })
      , babel({
          babelrc: true
        , plugins: [
          '@babel/plugin-external-helpers'
        ]
        , extensions: [
          ".jsx"
        ]
        , exclude: "node_module/**"
        , babelHelpers: "external"
        , presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-react'
          ]
          , [
            '@babel/preset-env'
            , {
                loose: true 
              , modules: 'auto'
              , debug: false
              , targets: {
                browsers: '> 1%, IE 11, not op_mini all, not dead'
                , node: 10
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      })
];
let commonExtenal = [
      'inferno'
      , 'inferno-server'
      , 'inferno-router'
      , 'fastify'
      , 'fastify-plugin'
      , 'assert'
      , 'hyperscript'
      , 'inferno-hyperscript'
      , 'hyperscript-helpers'
]
const clean = function(cb) {
    const deleted = del.sync(['dist/**', '!dist'], {force: true});
    console.log('Deleted paths:\n', deleted.join('\n'));
    cb();
}
async function buildPlugin() {
    const bundle = await rollup.rollup({
        input: 'src/index.js'
        , plugins: commonPlugins
        , external: commonExtenal
    });
    return bundle.write({
        output: {
            file: 'dist/bundle.js'
            , format: 'cjs'
            , exports: 'default'
        }
    });
}
async function buildExample() {
    const bundle = await rollup.rollup({
          input: 'src/example.js'
        , plugins: commonPlugins
        , external: commonExtenal
    });
    return bundle.write({
        output: {
            file: 'dist/example.js'
            , format: 'cjs'
           // , exports: 'default'
        }
    });
}
exports.build = series(clean, buildPlugin, buildExample);
```

all work fine.

best regards,
Leonardo